# Possible to change the layout of 1 block only?

Tags: layout, static-block

after some searching I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

I have a website with the 2coluns-left layout (and some cms pages with 1 column layout. Now I put a cms block at the bottom of my page (right above the footer) and would like to have it on the whole width of the site which would be 1 column layout, but only for this block.

Is this possible for cms static blocks?

Thanks a lot for your help!

edit:

there is also unother problem I just discovered. The block I am talking about should only be seen on the homepage, but it is shown on every single page. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Just call the block in the 1 column layout template file and style it to be 100% width?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this too and give you some feedback :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old without an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to append it to the footer, any other way would require you to edit the template files.

In your `local.xml` add the block to the footer.

```
[...]
<reference name="footer">
<block type="cms/block" name="footer_block">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your_block_id</block_id></action>
</block> 
</reference>
[...]
```

and call it from the `page/html/footer.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_block');?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought about it too, to append it to the footer. This will be my emergency solution ;-)  Could you explain some details about the template files editing? Which file(s) and what to edit?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the files to edit. Hope it works out.

Comment: Thanks for your input. In the meantime I found another solution for me. I created a new layout especially for the home-page. There I integrated a block at the bottom (above the footer) with the width of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're new to Magento, Welcome!

The files you are looking to modify are located in:

**/app/design/front-end/default/ACTIVE_TEMPLATE/template/page**

You'll need a file editor such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Some good resources for template modifications can be found by googling specific questions but most can be found on www.magentocommerce.com

[Designer's Guide to Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/how-magento-builds-content)

[Introuducing The Magento Layout](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/30/introducing-magento-layout/)

An additional tip is to use the template hints in the admin panel located at:

```
System-->Configuration
Select Store View (top left under Current Configuration Scope)
Select Developer (at the bottom left under "Advanced")
Template Path Hints --> Set to YES (un-select "Use website")
```

Once that's done, refresh your store view page to see what files are being called where for your active template.

Feel free to search magento.stackexchange.com for questions you may have, if you find no answer post and someone will lend you a hand.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the welcome and the links. I am not totally new to Magento but still have some knwoledge gaps. I already know the template hints, a lot of template and layout files but I don't know how to do this with the 1 block I talked about in my original post. I will go through your links but I already googled for days and still don't got my answer ...